# jQuery dialog dissappearing act?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery / jQueryUI to do some simple cookie checking on certain link types..

I want to check the cookie value on certain links and fire a form dialog if that value is met.

i.e.

```
<p id="clickLowValueAsset"><a href="page2.html" id="basic">go to page 2</a></p>
```

effectively firing this function on each click of type 'clickLowValueAsset'..

```
function checkLowValueCookie()
{
    cookie_value=getCookie('assetPoints');   
    if (cookie_value != -1)
    {
        if (cookie_value>20) {
            $('#lowValueSurvey').dialog('open');
        }
        else 
        {
            setCookie('assetPoints',(parseInt(cookie_value) + 3),30);
        }
    }
}
```

--

My form dialog is as follows:

```
$(function(){  
        $('#lowValueSurvey').dialog({
            bgiframe: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 500,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                Submit: function(){
                <!-- todo -->
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Everything works great.. The dialog 'lowValueSurvey' is displayed correctly when the cookie condition is met.. However it immediately disappears after firing dialog.open; I think the href click happens causing the form dialog to disappear. I want to force the user to act on the form.. Either submit it or Close it -

How can I prevent this behavior? Or is does a better method exist to force dialog popups/form on a certain cookie condition?

thank you!

patrick

Answer (score 0):

If it is the href trying to navigate to a new page add return false to the end of the function.

```
function checkLowValueCookie()
{
    cookie_value=getCookie('assetPoints');   
    if (cookie_value != -1)
    {
        if (cookie_value>20) {
            $('#lowValueSurvey').dialog('open');
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            setCookie('assetPoints',(parseInt(cookie_value) + 3),30);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to catch it.. It disappears after the function is complete and prior to the next onReady();